# Why can't I access my own folder with permission 644?

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server

I can’t access a WordPress folder that was created with my user and with permission 644. Is it correct? When I try to access the folder I have this result:

```
mdm-suporte@localhost:~$ cd public_html/
-bash: cd: public_html/: Permission denied
```

Also Apache results 403 error. Only with permission 755 I can access the folder and apache works.

Any thing wrong?

Comment: Apache runs as another user under normal conditions, and often needs the entire path to give it access (eg \home, \home\username, \home\username\htdocs\, etc), and many types of files will require execute rights to be served.

Answer (score 8):

Folders must be executable to be accessed. Observe:

With 644 permissions on the directory:

```
[Mjolnir:~]mkdir test
[Mjolnir:~]chmod 644 test
[Mjolnir:~]ls -l | grep test
drw-r--r--  2 USER USER       4096 Jun  1 15:03 test/
[Mjolnir:~]ls -l test
ls: cannot access 'test/.': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'test/..': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ./
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ../
[Mjolnir:~]cd test
-bash: cd: test: Permission denied
```

With 755 permissions on the same directory:

```
[Mjolnir:~]chmod 755 test
[Mjolnir:~]ls -l | grep test
drwxr-xr-x  2 USER USER       4096 Jun  1 15:03 test/
[Mjolnir:~]ls -l test
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 USER USER 4096 Jun  1 15:03 ./
drwxr-xr-x 57 USER USER 4096 Jun  1 15:04 ../
[Mjolnir:~]cd test
[Mjolnir:test]
```

Answer (score 3):

The "execute" flag on directory gives accesses to filesystem objects under the directory. The "read" flags gives access to directory contents. So starting with:

```
test
├── file1
└── file2
```

If you remove the execute flag, you can still list the contents:

```
>chmod -x test
> echo test/*
test/file1 test/file2
```

but you cannot access the contents:

```
>cat test/file1
cat: test/file1: Permission denied
```

You can't even get information on these files since this is done by accessing their inode, which is what the lack of execution privileges prevents you to do:

```
stat test/file1
stat: cannot stat 'test/file1': Permission denied
```

Now, if you keep the execution privilege but remove the read privilege, the situation is the  opposite:

```
>chmod +x-r test
```

You cannot list the directory contents:

```
>ls test
ls: cannot open directory 'test': Permission denied
```

But if you know what it contains, you can access the corresponding inodes:

```
>stat test/file1
  File: 'test/file1'
  Size: 6               Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 24642501    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      me)   Gid: ( 1000/      me)
Access: 2019-06-01 09:07:30.300676842 +0200
Modify: 2019-06-01 08:53:14.811834525 +0200
Change: 2019-06-01 08:53:14.811834525 +0200
```

And so access the contents:

```
>cat test/file1
File1
```

Comment: WTF, would have searched for hours and wouldn't have come up with this! 
Thank your very much!